# DNS for Pod in another Kubernetes cluster on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, dns, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to connect to the MongoDB replica set that is hosted in another Kubernetes cluster of the same GCP project. I want to use [DNS names](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the connection string.

I was able to connect to mongodb hosted in the same cluster using this connection string:

```
mongodb://<pod-name>.<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:27017,<pod-name>.<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:27017/?replicaSet=<rs-name>
```

So my question is:

Is it possible to use the DNS name to reference the pod in another cluster? I looked through [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and it states:

> Any pods created by a Deployment or DaemonSet have the following DNS
> resolution available:
>
> `pod-ip-address.deployment-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example.`

But I am not sure what is the format of the `cluster-domain.example` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use Kubernetes Service DNS(CoreDNS) to access a pod from outside the kubernetes cluster even from another kubernetes cluster. You need to expose the mongodb pod via `LoadBalancer`(recommended) or `NodePort` type service and access it using `LoadBalancer endpoint` or `NodeIP:NodePort` from the other kubernetes cluster.